# Hold dynamically added data in listView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have Designed a ListView in which I have added data dynamically but when i refreshed or restart my app ,array size become zero/no data in listView that I have added previously.How can I hold the data in my listView and add data in to same.if I could able to hold it then ,can easily add data to it.

Activity 2:(i have intent the array from activity 1 to here)

```
    ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.AcceptedList);

    ArrayList<PendingPickupBEAN>  listObject = (ArrayList<PendingPickupBEAN>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("referArray");

    Log.d(TAG," size of intent list " +listObject.size());


    CustomListViewAdapterGet customListViewAdapterGet = new CustomListViewAdapterGet(this,R.layout.list_item_accepted,listObject);
    listView.setAdapter(customListViewAdapterGet);
```

}

class CustomListViewAdapterGet  extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<PendingPickupBEAN> obj ;



    public CustomListViewAdapterGet(Context context, int resourceId,
                                    ArrayList<PendingPickupBEAN> obj) {

        super(context, resourceId,obj);
        this.context = context;
        this.obj = obj;


        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }



    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_pickupID;
        TextView txt_address;
        Button btn_More;



    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {




    final    ArrayAdapter<PendingPickupBEAN> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<PendingPickupBEAN>
                (Activity_Pickup.this,R.layout.list_item_accepted,R.id.Accepted_pickupID);

        final CustomListViewAdapterGet.ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new CustomListViewAdapterGet.ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_accepted, null);
            holder.txt_pickupID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Accepted_pickupID);
            holder.btn_More = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_More);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CustomListViewAdapterGet.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt_pickupID.setText(obj.get(position).getPickupID());


        holder.btn_More.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                holder.btn_More.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccept);


            }
        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

Comment: post the code snippet for relavant answers

Comment: How you are adding data in ArrayList. Post your code for more help.

Comment: I have shared my code here. I have checked the size of my array too after adding accepted item it's showing the expected size but, when I re-start my app array size becomes zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store you Data on Some permanent storage

[Store Data in DataBases](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

[Use SharedPreffernce](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could store your data in database.